# Are there any example of creating emptyElement()?

Tags: ckeditor5, ckeditor5-plugin

I created my plugin with the `createAttributeElement()` method. But, it should not wrap the text. For that I think I have to use `createEmptyElement()`. So I want to know are there any examples or anything I can refer to?

And I have already saw the image plugin example it is very complicated and the command of image plugin is different from my usage. The image plugin command uses `insertContent()` or `insertObject()` method which will remove the selected content from the editor and my requirement is different from that. I want to keep the selected content.

```
const schema = this.editor.model.schema

        schema.extend('$text', {
            allowAttributes: ['info']
        })

    conversion.attributeToAttribute({
                model: 'info',
                view: 'data-info'
            })
    
    conversion.for('upcast').elementToAttribute({
                view: {
                    name: 'primary',
                    attributes: ['data-info']
                },
                model: {
                    key: 'info',
                    value: (viewElement, conversionApi)=>{
                        const value = viewElement.getAttribute('info')
                        return value;
                    }
                }
            })
            conversion.for('downcast').attributeToElement({
                model: {
                    key: 'info'
                },
                view: (value, {writer})=>{
                    const attributeEl = {}
                    attributeEl['data-info'] = value
    
                    return writer.createAttributeElement('primary', attributeEl)
                },
                converterPriority: 'high'
            })
```

This is working fine. But, when I do createEmptyElement() in the downcast. It showing `view-writer-wrap-invalid-attribute`. What should be the way to create the emptyElement?